# Code blocks in cached partial views

Tags: c#, for-loop, outputcache, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm using OutputCache on a partial view which also contains the helper functions from [ForLoop.HtmlHelpers](https://bitbucket.org/forloop/forloop-htmlhelpers/wiki/Home) to help render scripts blocks right before the closing `<body>` tag.

```
<p>
    <span class='some-class'>@Model.somedata</span>
    <span class='placeholder'>@Model.anotherdata</span>
</p>
using (Html.BeginScriptContext())
{
    Html.AddScriptBlock(
        @<script>
        (function () {
            // do some work, could be ajax loading or any html formatting in js
        }());
        </script>
   );
}
```

And here's my sample controller function:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
[OutputCache(Duration = 120)] // using 120 sec as a sample
public PartialViewResult SomePartialView()
{
    using (Entities entities = new Entities())
    {
        return PartialView("SomePartialView", entities.GetMeSomeData());
    }
}
```

The obvious problem being that output caching will cause the `Html.AddScriptBlock(...)` to not execute as it will just spit the cached partial view results from before and will not proceed to execute any C# code inside the partial view (the cshtml file) - thus fails to add the needed script blocks when using cached results. Of course, I can get around this issue by moving the calls to adding the scriptblocks to the parent container page but that doesn't seem ideal to me. First question is whether anyone has a better idea or suggestion for getting around this particular problem? Perhaps I'm missing the obvious and better fix to this problem.

To give some insight into to the context of the problem I'm trying to solve, we have some results to display on the page but which require some custom timestamps to let the user know how old it is (custom messages like "6 minutes ago", "an hour ago", etc). Obviously, cached results will display stale messages so I'm using javascript to display the correct formatted message on page load. In the future, we'll also be wanting to do some lazyloading of specific data for partial views that we would like to output cache.

Second question is to the developers of [ForLoop.HtmlHelpers](https://bitbucket.org/forloop/forloop-htmlhelpers/wiki/Home): is it possible to add support for executing codeblocks for output cache? Or is there a way to configure output caching to execute codeblocks?